# How to prove this by induction?

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations

The sequence ${u_n}$ is given by the recurrence relation

$u_{n+1}=u_n-2 $ for n = 1,2,3, ...,

and the initial term $u_1=-1$

Prove by induction that $\sum^m_{n=1} u_n = -m^2$ for att $m\geq 1$

I get stuck in the induction step.

Comment: It is easier to help if you show how far you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly the result holds for $m=1:$ $\sum_{n=1}^{1}u_n=u_1=-1=-1^2$.

Assume the result holds for $m=k$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Then 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{k}u_n=-k^2.$$

Consider when $n=k+1$. We have $u_k=-2k+1$ and so
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{k+1}u_n&=u_{k+1}+\sum_{n=1}^{k}u_n \\
&=(u_k-2)-k^2 \\
&=-2k-1-k^2 \\
&=-(k+1)^2.
\end{align}$$

Hence the result holds by induction.

Comment: How did you get that $u_k = -2k+1$?

Comment: Well, given the above specification, $u_1=-1, u_2=-3, u_3=-5$, so by induction $u_k=-2k+1$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all show $u_n=-2n+1$ for all $n$

Then you have $$\sum_{n=1}^{m+1} u_n=\sum_{n=1}^m u_n+u_{m+1}=-m^2+u_m-2=-m^2-2m+1-2=-m^2-2m-1=-(m+1)^2$$

Comment: how do you show that $u_n=-2n+1$?

Comment: @pillikasnazsaxc The easiest way is induction over $n$ : $u_1=-2+1=-1$ is true. Now, $u_{n+1}=u_n-2=-2n+1-2=-2(n+1)+1$ ; Done.